# Should I index my PartitionKey when using cosmosDB

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to Cosmos DB and I am wondering if I should create an index for my PartitionKey. For example, let's suppose I choose a non-unique ID to be my partition key. Here are some sample data:

| uniqueId | someProperty | partitionKey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some data | 1 |
| 2 | some more data | 1 |
| 3 | some more data | 1 |
| 4 | some more data | 2 |
| 5 | some more data | 2 |

And let's assume I want to query all the items that have partitionKey = 2. Should I add an index on partitionKey, or this column is optimized just by the fact that it is partitioned?

Comment: Are you looking to create a custom index solution, because by default, Azure Cosmos DB automatically indexes every property for all items in your container without having to define any schema or configure secondary indexes.

Comment: Without an index on partition key the best that Cosmos will be able to do is direct the request to the correct physical partition for `partitionKey = 2` - that physical partition may hold many logical partition keys so the index is needed to identify the matching documents within the partition efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking about if you need to index it manually, Cosmos DB automatically indexes every property for all items. If you are talking about explicitly adding index policy then Yes, if you have disabled default indexing policy and need to filter by partition key then you should add an index to it.